# How to load values into the same JSP page on button click event

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have JSP page with one button "Load" and two textfields - "Weather" and "Companions". On click of the button it should call the controller and the controller has to load values typed in textfields into the table of the same JSP page. 
How can I do that? When I click on "Load", nothing happens.

**JSP page**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Context information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="weather">Weather</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="weather" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companions">Companions</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companions" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
                <table border="1" cellspacing="1" align="center"
                    style="margin-top: 160px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Weather</th>
                        <th>Companions</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${weather}</td>
                        <td>${companions}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<button onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href;">Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.test1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Test1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/context", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView context() {
        return new ModelAndView("context", "command", new Context());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/context", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String loadData(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Context context, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("weather", context.getWeather());
      model.addAttribute("companions", context.getCompanions());
      return "result";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadData", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public @ResponseBody String loadData(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Context context, ModelMap model) {
/** here i am assuming context.getWeather() and context.getCompanions() returns string or at least values you can convert to string using toString() method. If you need to convert them to string then you will need to change the code to context.getWeather().toString() + context.getCompanions().toString() **/

  return context.getWeather() + context.getCompanions();
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadAjaxString() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/loadData.html',
        success : function(data) {
             var weather = data.substring(0, endOfIndexofWeather);
             var companion = data.substring(endOfIndexofWeather);
            $('#tdWeather').val(weather );
            $('#tdcompanions').val(companion);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I did all these updates. The button is defined as `<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>`. However, on click event opens the page `results.jsp`. I want to avoid opening this page and load all data into the table of the same page `context.jsp`. Someone suggested to use Ajax, but is there any way to avoid using it?

Comment: What you are trying to do requires Ajax, you are trying to update just a portion of the web page as to avoid a full page reload.   To achieve this , you will need to use jquery ajax library and also annotate your string class with  @ResponseBody.  After which you will need to write a function where you define you ajax settings in Jquery. However since you case is pretty simple, i will advice you to just return a string from spring and then have java script render the value of the string in the table td. I will send you a sample code. This is the easiest quick and dirty way to do this.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate if you could update your answer according to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, i believe you are only using the loadData method to display date on your jsp page as you are not using it to save data to the server? So in this case it would be more appropriate to change it to get instead of post?

Comment: Probably you are right. Yes, I do not save data to the server.

Comment: This code would be a very minimal way of getting things done. However, if your getCompanion and getweather functions are returning say map object or collection type object, then the way to do this is not the quick and dirty way below. You will have to send json data from your server which is pretty easy also. I can show you that also

Comment: Thanks a lot. For completeness please show the case of JSON and I will accept your answer.

Comment: By the way, how should look the table? So far your examples does not work for me (still nothing happens on the button click event), probably because of the incorrect table `<table border="1" cellspacing="1" align="center" style="margin-top: 160px;">
       <tr>
           <th>Weather</th>
           <th>Companions</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>${weather}</td>
           <td>${companions}</td>
       </tr>
</table>  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loadAjaxString()" />`

Comment: If you follow the code, there is part of the jquery that shows Id attribute values for the td for weather and companion. so you should have <td id="#tdWeather">${weather}</td> and  id="#tdcompanions">${companions}</td> . Also remember that endOfIndexofWeather in the code should be replaced with the appropriate index value, which can be know by only you since you know the string that would be generated from the concatenation.

Comment: Also since you want to go the josn route. It is pretty straighforward. Just a little modification to the code. I will modify the code now to use json

Comment: It is pretty straighforward. Just a little modification to the code. I will modify the code now to use json. however you will need to download and add jackson library to your classpath, so java compiler and runtime can see it or you can add it to pom xml if you are using maven project. Can i change the code now to use json?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many issue in the code you have written first of all

Value given for `@RequestMapping` is duplicate give something else like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadData", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String loadData(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Context context, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("weather", context.getWeather());
      model.addAttribute("companions", context.getCompanions());
      return "result";
    }
```

Then 
form tag is missing
Something like `<form:form method="POST" action="loadData">`
has to be there

Then replace button with submit button

So your jsp page will look something like this, change the action as per your application

```
<form:form method="POST" action="loadData">
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="weather">Weather</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="weather" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companions">Companions</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companions" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
                <table border="1" cellspacing="1" align="center"
                    style="margin-top: 160px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Weather</th>
                        <th>Companions</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${weather}</td>
                        <td>${companions}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form:form>
```

Comment: The mappings have different request types GET/POST so are not duplicates and will be resolved correctly. It does however make sense to make the path a bit more descriptive.

Comment: I made these updates, but now on button click event loads a new jsp (results.jsp). I created results.jsp earlier, but the goal is to avoid loading this page. Instead I want to populate the table on the same jsp (context.jsp)

Comment: Maybe in loadData() I need to return `model` instead of String?

Comment: You need to make an Ajax request and return only the HTML of the table and replace the existing table.

Comment: Ok in that case instead of form submission you should use AJAX. Create a javascript method and call that method onclick on button, in that method call your controller and return result. Dump that result into the desired div or table

Comment: So, what would be a sample solution in case of AJAX?

Comment: $.ajax({url: "context.do", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }}); 
This would require jquery library